# Make a pandas.DataFrame's direction to right to left

Tags: pandas, dataframe, right-to-left

I want to make my pandas.DataFrame's direction to right to right to left.
Can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean? Can you provide a minimal example? Do you just want to invert the columns order: `df.iloc[:, ::-1]`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
# reverse column order of a dataframe
reversed_dataframe = dataframe[dataframe.columns[::-1]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Petros. But I want to make my dataframe like the image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iILnr.png

Comment: Do you want to move the first column in the end ?

Comment: No. I want to move the index columns to right

Comment: I am afraid, this cannot be done without declaring a new column. You can still add the index in a new column and append it on the right end of the dataframe, however it will be a normal named column.